# Can Helicobacter pylori be transmitted through saliva?

Tags: digestion, infection, gastroenterology, disease-transmission, stomach

I was wondering if you can get *Helicobacter pylori* (the bacteria that can cause gastritis and ulcers) by kissing a person,   if that person is infected with it?

Comment: Of note, 80% of people in the developing world are infected with H. Pylori. "Usually destroys the stomach lining" may be more accurately, "increases the risk for peptic ulcer disease".

Comment: Tnx for the comment but I've read that multiple times along with millions of posts and articles, suffering from digestive problems for over 5 years... Hoping to get a decent answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode of transmission of helicobacter is unknown but studies show that people with helicobacter infections may have it also in their saliva. So, in this study, 75% had helicobacter identified by molecular Probes.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC502720/

This has lead to some people saying that transmission by saliva is common.

https://publichealth.arizona.edu/outreach/health-literacy-awareness/hpylori/transmission